# superposing labels in Qgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing

i have Issue with labelling for overlapped lines,that i want to show the labels superposed , that mean:
`Label 1
       Label 2
       label 3`

on the Map in Qgis , the Lines are overlapped, and i need to show the information for every line as label but **lying upon each other**  here is how is look in Qgis now with attribute table.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what my basic labels look like, with "show all labels" option selected.
[image]

Add a new field, "Label_spacing"

[image]

Set the values of "Label_spacing" field to the distance you want the label for that feature to be from the line. I used 0, 5 and 10.

[image]

Use "Label_spacing" field for data-defined label placement setting (distance from line).

[image]

Here's what the labels look like now:

[image]

You can adjust the label spacing by changing the values in the field, "Label_spacing."

Note: All screenshots here are in QGIS 3.0, but the same process will work in QGIS 2.18, and possibly earlier versions as well.

Comment: @@ csk  thank you very much you are the best, this what i looking for, i hope that work for all 2530 overlapped lines that i have automaticaly , thank you again

Comment: You're welcome! Another tip: since you have so many overlapped lines, use the Field Calculator to fill in the Line_spacing values. An expression like @row_number*5 will work if the lines are all overlapping.

Comment: @@csk thank you again for your helpfull feedback, i think this with expression is littel bit complicated because i have diffeent overlapping lines sometimes 2 lines are overlaps sometimes 4.3,6 and so on and i have lines where no overlapping is, when i use your suggestion with @rown_number*5, i get too much distance to lines , ihave more than 200 Rows that mean distance =1000 in last line, i need expression or Sql query who check if there more than overlapped for example: overlapped lines = 4 , than insert in label_spacing successivly 0.00,5.00,10.00,15.00 and so on

Comment: That is a bit complicated. Try posting as a new question, with a link back to this one.